# How to add a binary file to a datagrid view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, binaryfiles, binary-data

im working on a c++ project and i was wondering if i can add the items of a datagrid without using a data base. Using a xxxxxx.dat file. Is that posible?

pd:sorry bout my english, im not an english-speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Create a couple of classes. One to describe a row in the file.
One to open up a list of the above.
add a method to load from the dat file, (and save to it?)
Then just bind your grid to the list class.

Another possible option would be ODBC Text driver, but there area  good few ifs and buts around that.